# Unable to find an element using CSS selector in CasperJS

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I am writing some test case using casperjs. I want to find a TD element inside a TR.

```
  <tr class="x-boundlist-item selectorCls">
        <td class="x-boundlist-item-td selectorTdCls" width="70%">64Columns</td>
       <td class="x-boundlist-item-td" align="right" style="padding-right:4px;">
               <a href="#" style="color:#15428B;"></a>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

I want to find a `TR` element by `css` class `x-boundlist-item selectorCls`
then inside this, I need to find the **first** `TD` element and fire click event.

I have used `.waitForSelector(".x-boundlist-item-td selectorTdCls",` which timed-out after sometime and does not return anything.

I have also tried using `var x = document.body.querySelectorAll('.x-boundlist-item-td selectorTdCls');`
and even that did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

`x-boundlist-item-td` and `selectorTdCls` are both classes on the same element so the selector should be `.x-boundlist-item-td.selectorTdCls`

`.x-boundlist-item-td selectorTdCls` would match something like...

```
<div class="x-boundlist-item-td">
  <selectorTdCls></selectorTdCls> <!-- << matches this -->
</div>
```

Comment: Aha, I tried `querySelectorAll` in a browser and I needed to wrap your example in a <table>....</table> for it to work. Does that work for you when you add it?

Comment: Yes.. its wrapped under a table. Can you show me the exact code you are using to select the element.

Comment: I have a HTML file which contains `<html><body><table><tr class="x-boundlist-item selectorCls"><td class="x-boundlist-item-td selectorTdCls" width="70%">64Columns</td><td class="x-boundlist-item-td" align="right" style="padding-right:4px;"><a href="#" style="color:#15428B;"></a></td></tr></table></body></html>` and in the console in Chrome, I type `document.body.querySelectorAll('.x-boundlist-item-td.selectorTdCls');` and that returns `[<td class=​"x-boundlist-item-td selectorTdCls" width=​"70%">​64Columns​</td>​]`

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. The problem is when I try it in chrome console, I get the desired result. But when I write same code in casperjs test, I do not get the desired result :(